# How to calculate time duration for the continuous variables having same value in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table that has the `user`, `logdate` and `color`.  I want to create a report that calculates the duration of the viewing for each color session.

```
Select 
t.user, t.url, datediff(mi,min(t.logdate),max(t.logdate)) as duration
from test as t
group by t.user, t.url
having duration > 0
order by logdate
```

problem is it is grouping all the same url into one group.

Here is the table

```
user    logTime               color
-----  --------------------  ------
abc 1   2014-09-01 00:00:12.0 green     
abc 2   2014-09-01 00:00:13.5 green     
abc 3   2014-09-01 00:00:30.0 amber     
abc 4   2014-09-01 00:00:30.0 amber     
abc 5   2014-09-01 00:00:31.5 amber     
abc 6   2014-09-01 00:00:32.0 amber     
abc 7   2014-09-01 00:00:32.2 amber     
abc 8   2014-09-01 00:00:33.5 amber     
abc 9   2014-09-01 00:00:33.0   red     
abc 10  2014-09-01 00:00:35.0   red     
abc 11  2014-09-01 00:00:35.2   red     
abc 12  2014-09-01 00:00:37.0   red     
abc 13  2014-09-01 00:00:41.0   red     
abc 14  2014-09-01 00:00:42.0   red     
abc 15  2014-09-01 00:00:42.2   red     
abc 16  2014-09-01 00:00:43.0   red     
abc 17  2014-09-01 00:00:44.7   red     
abc 18  2014-09-01 00:00:44.2   red     
abc 19  2014-09-01 00:00:45.5   red     
abc 20  2014-09-01 00:00:47.0   red     
abc 21  2014-09-01 00:00:48.7   red     
abc 22  2014-09-01 00:00:49.7   red     
abc 23  2014-09-01 00:00:49.7   red     
abc 24  2014-09-01 00:00:49.9   red     
abc 25  2014-09-01 00:00:50.9 green     
abc 26  2014-09-01 00:00:50.0 green     
abc 27  2014-09-01 00:00:52.0 green     
abc 28  2014-09-01 00:00:53.0 green     
abc 29  2014-09-01 00:00:54.0 green     
abc 30  2014-09-01 00:00:55.0 green     
abc 31  2014-09-01 00:00:55.0 green     
abc 32  2014-09-01 00:01:02.0 green     
abc 33  2014-09-01 00:01:03.7 green     
abc 34  2014-09-01 00:01:05.7 green     
abc 35  2014-09-01 00:01:07.0 green
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.
Please provide the desired output as well as the DDL for the table.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear as you are using `url` in your query but cannot find it in your sample data.

Just a note that you can make a main query put it a `CTE` and based on that you can make another query (You have ability to make a `JOIN` with your main table).

**Sample table**

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(url VARCHAR(10), [user] INT, logTime DATETIME2, color VARCHAR(10))
```

**Sample data**

```
INSERT @tbl
SELECT 'abc', 1  , '2014-09-01 00:00:12.0' , 'green' UNION ALL     
SELECT 'abc', 2  , '2014-09-01 00:00:13.5' , 'green' UNION ALL     
SELECT 'abc', 3  , '2014-09-01 00:00:30.0' , 'amber' UNION ALL     
SELECT 'abc', 4  , '2014-09-01 00:00:30.0' , 'amber' UNION ALL     
SELECT 'abc', 5  , '2014-09-01 00:00:31.5' , 'amber' UNION ALL     
SELECT 'abc', 6  , '2014-09-01 00:00:32.0' , 'amber' UNION ALL     
SELECT 'abc', 7  , '2014-09-01 00:00:32.2' , 'amber' UNION ALL     
SELECT 'abc', 8  , '2014-09-01 00:00:33.5' , 'amber' UNION ALL     
SELECT 'abc', 9  , '2014-09-01 00:00:33.0'   , 'red' UNION ALL     
SELECT 'abc', 10 , '2014-09-01 00:00:35.0'   , 'red' UNION ALL     
SELECT 'abc', 11 , '2014-09-01 00:00:35.2'   , 'red' UNION ALL     
SELECT 'abc', 12 , '2014-09-01 00:00:37.0'   , 'red' UNION ALL     
SELECT 'abc', 13 , '2014-09-01 00:00:41.0'   , 'red' UNION ALL     
SELECT 'abc', 14 , '2014-09-01 00:00:42.0'   , 'red' UNION ALL     
SELECT 'abc', 15 , '2014-09-01 00:00:42.2'   , 'red' UNION ALL     
SELECT 'abc', 16 , '2014-09-01 00:00:43.0'   , 'red' UNION ALL     
SELECT 'abc', 17 , '2014-09-01 00:00:44.7'   , 'red' UNION ALL     
SELECT 'abc', 18 , '2014-09-01 00:00:44.2'   , 'red' UNION ALL     
SELECT 'abc', 19 , '2014-09-01 00:00:45.5'   , 'red' UNION ALL     
SELECT 'abc', 20 , '2014-09-01 00:00:47.0'   , 'red' UNION ALL     
SELECT 'abc', 21 , '2014-09-01 00:00:48.7'   , 'red' UNION ALL     
SELECT 'abc', 22 , '2014-09-01 00:00:49.7'   , 'red' UNION ALL     
SELECT 'abc', 23 , '2014-09-01 00:00:49.7'   , 'red' UNION ALL     
SELECT 'abc', 24 , '2014-09-01 00:00:49.9'   , 'red' UNION ALL     
SELECT 'abc', 25 , '2014-09-01 00:00:50.9' , 'green' UNION ALL     
SELECT 'abc', 26 , '2014-09-01 00:00:50.0' , 'green' UNION ALL     
SELECT 'abc', 27 , '2014-09-01 00:00:52.0' , 'green' UNION ALL     
SELECT 'abc', 28 , '2014-09-01 00:00:53.0' , 'green' UNION ALL     
SELECT 'abc', 29 , '2014-09-01 00:00:54.0' , 'green' UNION ALL     
SELECT 'abc', 30 , '2014-09-01 00:00:55.0' , 'green' UNION ALL     
SELECT 'abc', 31 , '2014-09-01 00:00:55.0' , 'green' UNION ALL     
SELECT 'abc', 32 , '2014-09-01 00:01:02.0' , 'green' UNION ALL     
SELECT 'abc', 33 , '2014-09-01 00:01:03.7' , 'green' UNION ALL     
SELECT 'abc', 34 , '2014-09-01 00:01:05.7' , 'green' UNION ALL     
SELECT 'abc', 35 , '2014-09-01 00:01:07.0' , 'green'
```

**Query using [`CTE`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)**

```
;WITH C AS(
    SELECT color, DATEDIFF(MINUTE, MIN(logTime), MAX(logTime)) AS duration
    FROM @tbl
    GROUP BY color
)
SELECT * FROM C
WHERE duration > 0
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is classic SQL problem of grouping consecutive records.  You cannot group your records on the basis of "color" column only.  You need to generate some sort of session index for every color session.  Try following SQL to do so.  This is not a final solution but it will lead you to your desired results.  This just shows you a technique how you can combine consecutive records with same color and establish a session index for them.  Once you have the session index, grouping by it is just a snap.  Once your group by starts working fine, session duration will be easy to derive.

```
DECLARE @MyTableVar table(
    username nvarchar(100) NOT NULL,
    logTime datetime,
    color nvarchar(10));


insert into @MyTableVar values('abc', '2014-09-01 00:00:12.0', 'green');
insert into @MyTableVar values('abc', '2014-09-01 00:00:18.0', 'green');
insert into @MyTableVar values('abc', '2014-09-01 00:00:25.0', 'amber');
insert into @MyTableVar values('abc', '2014-09-01 00:00:27.0', 'amber');
insert into @MyTableVar values('abc', '2014-09-01 00:00:35.0', 'red');
insert into @MyTableVar values('abc', '2014-09-01 00:00:38.0', 'green');
insert into @MyTableVar values('abc', '2014-09-01 00:00:41.0', 'green');

drop table #tmp;

select *, (ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY logTime) - ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY color ORDER BY logTime)) As SessionIndex into #tmp from @MyTableVar order by logTime;

select SessionIndex, MAX(logTime) SessionStart, MIN(logTime) SessionEnd, DATEDIFF(SECOND, MIN(logTime), MAX(logTime)) AS SessionDurationSeconds from #tmp group by SessionIndex;
```

Here is the post that has details.

http://sqlmag.com/sql-server/solution-t-sql-puzzle-grouping-consecutive-rows-common-element

Answer (score 0):

It could be that you are not getting inaccurate results here, just that the finalized dates are formatted incorrectly. Consult the documentation of your particular type of SQL (MySQL, SQL Server, ...) to find out how to transform datetime differences into integers such as minute.